# Calculate Xively client downtime

Tags: xively

Am trying to calculate how long my IoT device is offline. MQTT has feature called Last Will and Testament. Is there a way to track how long the client has been down using Xively dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

Using MQTT's *last will testament* feature is certainly one of the ways to do it. Alternatively you could send *"pulse"* updates into a datastream and determine downtime if gap between pulses is greater then set period.